# Compiling default android applications

Tags: java, android

Can i compile applications that are part of android separately? Probably modify them?

I downloaded them from [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.4_r1) but have had no luck importing them into eclipse. I create a new android project then import the files. This shows missing Class errors, but I've downloaded all the dependencies listed on that page and included them in the compile path. I also tried hunting down the separate classes from [grepcode](http://grepcode.com) but they also require other files.

Of particular interest though is the STK App. I'd like to modify it so i can make STK calls from my application.

If anyone has successfully compiled any default android apps, i'd be glad to hear your experience.

Answer (score 0):

How do you import the files? Usually when I do that a recreate a new project and then copy the activities, sometimes create layouts, update the manifest information. It doesn't just work "out of the box".

If some classes are missing depends on which ones maybe try to change the api level. Some classes are available in the latest versions only.

Also it happened that some projects were compiled with ant then when you want to use that project with eclipse you have first have to delete the ant build file and then you will be able to import directly.

Comment: I imported the initial files by copying the souce code files from src/ and pasting them into the src/ folder for my eclipse project. Then i refresh eclipse, then clean. I do the same for the other classes i import. I don't see an ant build file though.

Comment: I had a look the actually require some "internal" classes. I am not sure but have a look here there are some internal classes, hope that helps http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/